# What is the meaning of jQuery enclosure in Javascript libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see a lot of third party javascript codes that are enclosed with jQuery like this:

```
$(function() {
  // ... javascript code
});
```

What is the purpose of enclosing with jQuery?

This is different from `$(document).ready(function() { /* ... */ });` right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is different from `$(document).ready(function() { /* ... */ } );` right?

No, it's only a shorthand. They are exactly the same, as you can read on [jQuery's website](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> - `$(document).ready(handler)`
> - `$().ready(handler)` (this is not recommended)
> - `$(handler)`